# Clean upgrade ubuntu server with exsiting setting and files

Tags: ubuntu, backup, upgrade

I have a ubuntu 11.04 server on my machine for AMP.

I want to grade this to 14.04 manually without do-release-upgrade command.
since I don't want to get any mess.

My plan is

1. backup some directories to other partition. (/home /etc ...)
2. backup packages which I current use
3. clean install 14.04
4. restore my packages, data, and settings

Questions.

1. which directories should I backup? /home /etc and others? maybe /var/log?
2. how can I backup my packages? below is correct?

   (on 11.04) sudo dpkg --get-selections "*" > pack_file

   (then on 14.04) sudo dpkg --set-selections < pack_file ; sudo apt-get -u dselect-upgrad
3. how can I backup other files and settings.

   for instance, sudo mv /backup/home /home is enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) You can keep /home so all your settings and data is saved. 
2.) Yes have used exactly same command and it worked perfectly.
sudo dpkg --set-selections < ~/packages && sudo apt-get -u dselect-upgrade 
3.) As in 1.